# GTMAppAuth 'presentingViewController' not found in the function declaration

Tags: ios, google-oauth

I want to integrate GTMAppAuth and GDrive as following the steps:

$ pod install

```
target 'GTMAppAuth Drive Example iOS' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'

  pod 'GTMAppAuth'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive'
end
```

$ open Example-iOS.xcworkspace

https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth/tree/master/Example-iOS

Copy the client ID to the clipboard from google console.
In GTMAppAuthExampleViewController.m update kClientID with new client id.

Finally, open Info.plist and fully expand "URL types" (a.k.a. "CFBundleURLTypes") and replace com.googleusercontent.apps.YOUR_CLIENT with the reverse DNS notation form of your client id (not including the :/oauthredirect path component).

But
Why error in the comment ?
My Xcode version is 8.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an opened issue on AppAuth's github: https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth/issues/21

The workaround for now seems to be to add this line to the Podfile:
`pod 'AppAuth', :inhibit_warnings => true`

Comment: After I add this line and recompile it . Xcode show 「 library not found for -lAppAuth」

Comment: I set the 「Build the active architecture only 」 to No.  The the -lAppAuth problem be solved

Comment: @Lveecode, I added the AppAuth but it gives me an error 'sharedApplication' is unavailable in application extensions or category for iOS.

Please help me.